# Fastapi with Custom Pydantic Schema with Generic, I need to auto generate example from a Pydantic Model

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

From topic title I don't know how to define the method `__get_pydantic_core_schema__` in `Other` class to return auto generate `CoreSchema` type from given Schema in argument for displaying example without self defining example in swagger UI docs.

Example picture and coding

[image]

Example value with self defining (I need other_member example with auto generate from Schema Member like attribute member example for doing something next)

My example code
I use pydantic v2

```
import uvicorn

from pydantic import BaseModel, GetCoreSchemaHandler
from pydantic_core import CoreSchema, core_schema
from fastapi import FastAPI
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, List, get_args

T = TypeVar("T")


class Other(Generic[T]):
    @classmethod
    def __get_pydantic_core_schema__(
        cls, __source: type[BaseModel], __handler: GetCoreSchemaHandler
    ) -> CoreSchema:
        member_model = get_args(__source)[0]  # Member model
        return core_schema.typed_dict_schema(
            {
                "first_name": core_schema.typed_dict_field(core_schema.str_schema()),
                "last_name": core_schema.typed_dict_field(core_schema.str_schema()),
            }
        )


class Member(BaseModel):
    first_name: str
    last_name: str = None
    age: int
    ...


class House(BaseModel):
    member: Member
    other_member: Other[Member]


app = FastAPI()


@app.post("/houses/", response_model=House)
async def create_house(house: House):
    return house


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

Comment: Does the `Other` class do anything besides overriding the `__get_pydantic_core_schema__` method?

Comment: I mean, why `other_member: Other[Member]` instead of `other_member: Member`?

Comment: Inside the `__get_pydantic_core_schema__` I will mapping the `Member` schema with my database model.